# How to rewrite a legacy url for tomcat using urlrewrite 4.0

Tags: tomcat, rewrite

I have urlrewrite installed.

We have a legacy base of computers that need to use a particular url (the important bits are in bold):

http://**old-server**/arsys/forms/**old-server**/RQC%3AServiceRequestConsole/RQC+User+View/

This app has the weird thing that it embeds the server name into the URL path. We are moving it to a new server, and need to change this URL. I have "old-server" aliased to the new-server IP, but I also need to rewrite that path to:

http://**new-server**/arsys/forms/**new-server**/RQC%3AServiceRequestConsole/RQC+User+View/

The rewrite rule I have is:

```
<rule>
    <from>/arsys/forms/old-server/RQC%3AServiceRequestConsole/RQC+User+View/</from>
    <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/arsys/forms/new-server/RQC%3AServiceRequestConsole/RQC+User+View/</to>
</rule>
```

But it seems to be croaking on the %3A (which is given explicitly in the shortcut in the legacy system.)

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get this rule right?

Comment: Try replacing `%3A` with its decoded character `:`.

Comment: or escaping the % (so \%3A) - untested, no clue if it'll help.

Comment: I did, that didn't seem to do it.